# No puedo enviar email con la función mail() de php en CentOS 7

Tags: php, webservice, email, centos

Bueno, tengo un problema con la función *mail* de PHP, cada vez que ejecuto este código:

```
<body>
    <p align="center">
        <font face="arial" size=4>
        <?php
            $para = "nare.phantasie.1990@gmail.com";
            $asunto = "Prueba de envío de email";
            $cabecera = "From: nrojas.orioncorp@gmail.com\r\n".
            "Reply-To: nrojas.orioncorp@gmail.com\r\n";
            $cuerpo = "Hola Mundo.";
            echo mail($para, $asunto, $cuerpo, $cabecera)?"Enviado.\n":"Lo sentimos, no se pudo enviar.\n";
        ?>
        </font>
    </p>
</body>
```

Entonces en el navegador se muestra el mensaje "Enviado." pero yo nunca veo el mensaje en mi bandeja de entrada de mi correo en gmail.
Yo siempre veo un mensaje en consola como "Tiene un mensaje nuevo en /var/spool/mail/root".
Mi servidor tiene **CentOS 7**, y tiene también **httpd** y **PHP5 instalados correctamente**.
**¿Cómo puedo enviar correos desde mi servidor web?**

Comment: @RicardoFernandez No nos  beneficia traducir sin saber si el autor va a entender las respuestas y no podrá contestar. Si te interesa tener esta pregunta, te recomiendo hacer una nueva de la cual seas el autor.

Comment: Yo soy el autor de esta pregunta, y entendería perfectamente las respuestas en inglés, no es necesario que traduzcan la pregunta y las respuestas. Sin embargo acabo de traducir la pregunta a petición vuestra.
Saludos y gracias de antemano (y).

Comment: @NeztorR.Surth no te molestes, pero simplemente que aquí es StackOverFlow en Español, si deseas hacerla en inglés hazla aquí  http://stackoverflow.com ;)

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero sería aclarar que. aunque recibas un valor `true` y muestres el mensaje "Enviado", eso no quiere decir que el mensaje se haya enviado. Simplemente que el correo ha sido aceptado para su envío, como se indica en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php):

> ### Valores devueltos
>
> Devuelve **TRUE** si el correo ha sido aceptado para su envío, de lo contrario **FALSE**.
>
> Es importante tener en cuenta que si el correo es aceptado para su envío, NO quiere decir que el correo haya alcanzado el destino indicado.

Como recibes `true`, eso quiere decir que PHP le ha pasado la información a tu servidor de correo. PHP ha hecho su parte, y a partir de ahí, lo que ocurra después estará fuera de su alcance. En una analogía con el mundo real: la persona (PHP) ha metido la carta en un sobre, le ha puesto un sello y la ha metido en el buzón; ahora es el trabajo del cartero (el servidor de correo) el distribuirla y entregarla al destinatario correcto.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, el primer paso (y sé que esto es una perogrullada) sería asegurarte de que tienes un servidor de correo SMTP instalado y corriendo en tu servidor, y/o de que el servidor está configurado para que mande las peticiones de correo a un servidor SMTP (en php.ini).

Si está todo bien configurado y corriendo como debiera pero sigues sin recibir mensajes, entonces debes revisar los logs del servidor de correo para ver qué es lo que está fallando en su parte. Puede que alguno de los parámetros no sea válido o no le guste algo en las cabeceras. Los logs deberían mostrar algún mensaje de error.

Si los logs no muestran ningún mensaje de error, sino que indican que el email se envió de manera correcta, entonces el problema pasaría a ser en el distribuidor de correo (en este caso GMail). Que puede estar marcando el mensaje como *spam* y tirándolo a la papelera directamente.

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota:** Para el envío de correo mediante **PHP** es necesario que este disponga de una correcta configuración.

Si nuestro web está en un servidor de un proveedor de hosting seguramente ya hayan configurado PHP para el envío de mails. Si estamos trabajando en un servidor propio, sí tendremos que configurar PHP.

PHP se configura en el archivo php.ini, donde debemos especificar datos como el servidor de correo saliente que debe de utilizar PHP para transferir los mensajes.

Dentro del php.ini, debemos buscar el epígrafe [mail function]. Dependiendo de nuestro sistema deberemos configurar de una manera u otra.

> **Nota:** Si se ejecuta correctamente la function mail, deberías revisar si el correo u mensaje esta o no marcando como **spam**

Un ejemplo la cual utilizo para enviar correo u mensaje.

```
<?php
$sender = $_POST['name'];
$return = $_POST['email'];
$message = nl2br($_POST['message']);

$to = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Message from Spyre Contact Form";

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($return) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($return) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$msg = "<html><body>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;'>New Contact Message</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "Sent by: <strong>".$sender."</strong><br />\r\n";
$msg .= "Respond to: <strong>".$return."</strong><br /><br />\r\n";
$msg .= "Message: <br />\r\n";
$msg .= "<em>".$message."</em><br />\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "Mensaje Enviado";
} else {
    echo "Error, al enviar mensaje";
}

?>
```

Parámetros adicionales:

```
//para el envío en formato HTML 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

//dirección del remitente 
$headers .= "From: Miguel Angel Alvarez <pepito@desarrolloweb.com>\r\n"; 

//dirección de respuesta, si queremos que sea distinta que la del remitente 
$headers .= "Reply-To: mariano@desarrolloweb.com\r\n"; 

//ruta del mensaje desde origen a destino 
$headers .= "Return-path: holahola@desarrolloweb.com\r\n"; 

//direcciones que recibián copia 
$headers .= "Cc: maria@desarrolloweb.com\r\n"; 

//direcciones que recibirán copia oculta 
$headers .= "Bcc: pepe@pepe.com,juan@juan.com\r\n";
```

> **Importante** Observar la documentación **php**
>   http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes **php 5.3** te puede decir que se envió el correo pero nunca llega a la bandeja de los correos (hasta el momento no se porque pero con **php 5.3** no funciona mail ya lo he probado) con **version 5.4 de php** en adelante si funciona